# What is an rpc network address?

Tags: go, json-rpc

I'm trying to use random.org to generate random numbers in my go program. It seems like I need to establish a json-rpc connection, so I'm trying to use the method `jsonrpc.Dial(network, adress)`. All the api says is that I need to invoke `https://api.random.org/json-rpc/2/invoke`; what should I use as the network (and what is a network)?

Answer (score -1):

If you look at [the source code](https://golang.org/src/net/rpc/jsonrpc/client.go?s=2889:2944#L108) for `jsonrpc.Dial`, you see that the `network` argument is passed straight on to [`net.Dial`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#Dial), whose godoc explains:

> Known networks are "tcp", "tcp4" (IPv4-only), "tcp6" (IPv6-only), "udp", "udp4" (IPv4-only), "udp6" (IPv6-only), "ip", "ip4" (IPv4-only), "ip6" (IPv6-only), "unix", "unixgram" and "unixpacket".

Comment: So which one should I use? I don't really understand networks, sorry. I've tried `jsonrpc.Dial("tpc", "api.random.org/json-rpc/2/invoke:https")`, and variations but nothing seems to work, all resulting in `panic: dial tcp: lookup api.random.org/json-rpc/2/invoke: no such host`

Comment: @lolad, use `Dial("tcp", "api.random.org:443")` for HTTPS. `api.random.org/json-rpc/2/invoke` is not a valid hostname.

Comment: Thanks, it seems to get through now at least, but can you please explain the 443? And also discarding the `json-rpc/2/invoke`, surely the methods won't work correctly?

Comment: 443 is the port for HTTPS. You probably need to do some basic reading about HTTP. We can't really give you a complete primer on the basics of IP and HTTP in comments (or answers) on SO.